# deducing return type to be type of template arguments method

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

It's hard for me to explain in English exactly what I mean, but the following non-compilable code might illustrate what I'm after:

```
template<class T>
auto fn(T t) -> decltype(T::method_call())
{
    return t.method_call();
}
```

Basically I want the function to return whatever it is T's method returns. What's the syntax to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++14, you can use deduced return type to simply say:

```
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) fn(T t) { return t.method_call(); }
```

You can also use the trailing return type to specify the same thing:

```
template <typename T>
auto fn(T t) -> decltype(t.method_call()) { return t.method_call(); }
```

Comment: And without trailing return type
`template <typename T> decltype (std::declval<T>().method_call()) fn(T);`.